# Change LoadTest setup during run

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying to figure out how to change LoadTest setup during it's run. E.g. I need to run 5 tests included in Loadtest mix during 90 minutes(25 simultaneous users), than add one more test to the mix, which will run 25 simultaneous user for next 90 minutes. I know that with loadtest plugins we can change some properties, but still didn't find a way to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the tests in the test mix of a scenario cannot be altered at run time. A load test plugin has access to the names of the tests in a scenario via `m_loadTest.Scenarios[N].TestNames` where `N` is an index into the collection of scenarios. The Intelitype help for `TestNames` states `Gets an array of the test names that are included in the scenario.` There does not appear to be any way to add the other properties of a test such as its percentage or its rate of occurrence.

One way of achieving something similar to what the question wants is to have two scenarios. The first scenario has the initial 5 tests and 25 users, it runs for the entire 180 minutes of the test. The second scenario has all 6 tests and one user, it has a `Delay start time` of 90 minutes. This gives 26 users for the second half of the test, but that can be fixed with a plugin. The `Heartbeat` plugin of the load test could be used to decrease the number of users in the first scenario to 24 after 90 minutes, by assigning to `m_loadTest.Scenarios[N].CurrentLoad` for a suitable `N`.

Having the 5 test and 6 test scenarios running at the same time may give the wrong proportions of test cases. If equal ratios are wanted throughout then for the second half there will be 5 tests at 20% each in one scenario and 6 tests at 16% or 17% each in the other scenario. Leading to the 6th test case being about 8% overall.

Another approach has the two scenarios with 5 and 6 tests as above. This time make the `heartbeat` plugin slowly decrease the number of users in the 5 scenario test and at the same time increase the users in the other. This should avoid the problem with wrong proportions of the tests.

Comment: △1 Welcome to 10k! :P

Comment: Thank you @TravisJ. I have been looking forward to seeing what 10K allows me here.

Comment: Here are two interesting deleted posts that you now have access to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/380819/1026459, https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/1026459 . You used to get to see all the fun deleted SO meta posts too, but now they are over at MSE :(

Comment: They have some interesting reading which I will check tomorrow as it is now the end of my day in the UK. Thanks again @TravisJ.

Comment: @AdrianHHH If I get this correctly, you are suggesting having two loadtests running in parallel, after first reaches 90 minutes? If that's the case, I don't think you can start second loadtest while one is running. Is there an option to add up users on the certain webtest scenario during run, I think that could work for me?

Comment: @miskegm No. Two scenarios in one load test. You might also read about using a stepped load pattern. I think there are some examples in my other answers here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Got it. The first solution worked out well. Thank you